# Does Counter-Strike: Source works in LAN with a normal Counter Strike?

Tags: counter-strike, counter-strike-source

I was considering buying a Counter-Strike: Source on Steam, but first I would like to know if it works in LAN mode (that mode you create a server to play with your friends in a LAN) with normal Counter-Strike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter-Strike:source can play on LAN, but only with other Counter-Strike:source players.

You cannot LAN with other versions of the game.